# Parse.com: The server returned an invalid response

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

With the code below, I've this error:

`{ code : 107, message : 'The server returned an invalid response.' }`

```
at User.test.js:65
at User.test.js:60
at wrappedRejectedCallback (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5269)
at reject (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5214)
at wrappedRejectedCallback (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5281)
at reject (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5214)
at /Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5275
at wrappedRejectedCallback (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5269)
at /Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5295
at runLater (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5286)
at then (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5296)
at wrappedRejectedCallback (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5276)
at reject (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5214)
at wrappedRejectedCallback (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5281)
at reject (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5214)
at /Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5275
at wrappedRejectedCallback (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5269)
at /Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5295
at runLater (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5286)
at then (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5296)
at wrappedRejectedCallback (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5276)
at reject (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5214)
at /Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5275
at wrappedRejectedCallback (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5269)
at /Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5295
at runLater (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5286)
at then (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5296)
at wrappedRejectedCallback (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5276)
at reject (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5214)
at /Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5259
at wrappedRejectedCallback (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5269)
at /Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5295
at runLater (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5286)
at then (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5296)
at wrappedResolvedCallback (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5260)
at resolve (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5193)
at wrappedResolvedCallback (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5262)
at resolve (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5193)
at /Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5257
at wrappedResolvedCallback (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5253)
at resolve (/Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:5193)
at /Users/me/Documents/Developments/backend/bower_components/parse/parse.js:8344
```

Here is my code:

```
// MAIN.JS
Parse.Cloud.define('findUserWithUsername', function(request, response) {
  console.log('MAIN => findUserWithUsername');
  user.findUserWithUsername(request.params.username, response.success, response.error);
});

// USER.JS
exports.findUserWithUsername = function(username, success, failure) {
  console.log('findUserWithUsername - username: ' + username);
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  console.log('findUserWithUsername - query created')
  query.equalTo("username", username).first().then(function(_user) {
    if (typeof _user !== 'undefined') {
      console.log('findUserWithUsername success -> ' + _user);
      success(_user);
    } else {
      console.log('findUserWithUsername success -> no user found');
      success(null);
    }
  }, function(_error) {
    console.log('findUserWithUsername - error: ' + _error);
    failure(_error);
  });
}

// USER.TEST.JS
function deletePreviousUser(username) {
  console.log('deletePreviousUser');
  return Parse.Cloud.run("findUserWithUsername", {username: username}).then(function(user) {
    console.log('findUserWithUsername succeed');
    return (user == undefined) ? Parse.Promise.as() : Parse.Cloud.run("deleteUser", {userId: user.id});
  }).then(function(result) {
    return Parse.Promise.as();
  }, function(_error) {
    return Parse.Promise.error(_error);
  });
}
```

I never had such a error message with Parse.com and I've no idea of what does it mean. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I experienced the same error.
This error had started to occur suddenly without modifing codes.
In my case, changing code from "response.success();" to ""response.success("");" fixed the problem.

Please try to change the line "success(null);"
 to "success("");"

Comment: Thanks for your help. I identified three cases where this error is thrown: `success()`,  `success(null)` and `success(undefined)`. The fun thing is there is no such indication in the documentation. Moreover, there is an example with `success()` in the documentation: https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-logging-from-cloud-code

Comment: Yes, I had the bad surprise that a lot of code in the `cloud_code` suddenly doesn't work anymore. It's been more than a month now that the problem occurred and still no news/bug fixes from Parse...

Comment: Is there any update on this? I'm encountering this exact issue and the above fix works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it solved by restart the Parse Local Server.